# Spring-cloud-stream DLQ message is trimmed to representing POJO

Tags: json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I Have a spring-cloud-stream Kafka application, than consumes Json messages. these Jsons (string payloads) are represented in the code as POJOs, and a dedicated deserializer successfully maps the input to the Java type.

The problem is, when the DLQ mechanism is executed due to an error, the DLQ publisher only sends the mapped POJO as the failed record, and not the original input. and so, in case i only map part of the data in the POJO, the DLQ message is different than the original message.

This behavior does not make sense to me, since if i need to merge this messages after a bug fix that includes modification of the POJO (mapping more fields) i will not be able to do so (the added fields will not exist in the failing message).

Example:
original message -

```
{
"id": "abc",
"name": "John",
"age": 39
}
```

POJO:

```
class Person {
private String id;
private String name;
}
```

failing record (in DLQ topic):

```
{
"id": "abc",
"name": "John"
}
```

- age is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Show your configuration (YAML or Properties). The default deserializer is the `ByteArrayDeserializer` so what gets sent to the DLT should be the original raw bytes; if you are using the `JsonDeserializer`, the data will be lost before Spring even sees it.

For this use case, you should NOT use the retry and DLQ configuration in the binder (set max attempts to 1), instead use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` to inject a suitably configured `DefaultErrorHandler`, configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

The error handler goes into the container's `commonErrorHandler` property.

See the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters